# problem while installing application to android device

Tags: android, flutter

this is the trace of shell, can anyone guide me to how to resolve this issue.

```
    [ +489 ms] adb: failed to install D:\Flutter_Applications\test2\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk:
    [   +3 ms] Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk... (completed)
    [   +4 ms] Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
    [   +5 ms] adb: failed to install D:\Flutter_Applications\test2\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk:
    [   +1 ms] Warning: Failed to install APK.
    [   +1 ms] Error launching application on SM J710F.
    [  +41 ms] "flutter run" took 25,086ms.

    #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:26:3)
    #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:404:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
    #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:401:18)
    #3      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
    #4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
    #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
    #6      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
    #7      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
    #8      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
    #9      Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
    #10     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
    #11     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:28:18)
    #12     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:295:13)
    #13     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
    #14     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
    #15     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
    #16     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
    #17     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
    #18     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
    #19     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
    #20     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
    #21     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
    #22     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
    #23     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
    #24     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
    #25     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
    #26     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
    #27     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
    #28     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
    #29     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

Comment: Ensure you have enough free space. If you have multiple Flutter projects installed on the device/emulator, delete them and try again.

Comment: if you run `adb install -t -r 
 "D:\Flutter_Applications\test2\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk"` from terminal (command prompt) did you get a more meaningflu error?

Comment: i already have much space in my mobile device and i have already deleted previous app containing same name.

Comment: when i run this command then it prompts this error.

Comment: adb: failed to install D:\Flutter_Applications\test1\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk:

Comment: yes i have 27 different flutter apps installed in my device. Now i have tried to install same application in different device and it runs properly and wont occur an error. But when i try to install on previous device it prompts an error, don't know why? but may be due to i have installed many flutter apps in my android device. But it wont make error on many number of different apps? Kindly anyone answer my confusion!

Comment: @ShabberNaqvi Please provide all the adb log. After the colon (':') usually you have a better explanation on why adb failed to install the apk.

Comment: thanx dear now I have formatted my device and that error has gone, thanks for your coordination.